# grab only name column of lsof?

Tags: lsof

I have the following command that works great:

```
sudo lsof -w -c smbd -u myuser | grep '.txt'
```

I just want to get the full path to the file name part of the returned output, the "NAME" column, to put in a report. What is the easiest way to just grab the NAME column?

Comment: read `man cut`.

Comment: Not sure if this is the BEST way to do it, but this works:
sudo lsof -F -w -c smbd -u myuser | grep '.txt'
It appears that the -F splits the output into separate lines per column, and the grep does the job. Happy to hear if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: `-Fn` will show only the `"file name, comment, Internet address"`. By the way, your command will show processes which are **either** owned by the user, **or** whose process name is "smbd". If you're looking only for processes who are **both** smbd **and** owned by the user, you should add the `-a` flag. Except for that, you were pretty close to the answer with the `-F` flag, you just missed the `n` afterwards. Submit it as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo lsof -w -c smbd -u myuser | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 9 | grep '.txt'
```

tr - replaces repeated blank spaces with a single space.
cut - outputs exclusively field\column 9.

Comment: If the file names contains spaces after `cut -d' ' -f 9` It will also cut the file name leaving the first part of the filename (`filename\ 1`->`filename`)

change `-f 9` -> `-f 9-` to correct this behavior.

`sudo lsof -w -c smbd -u myuser | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 9- | grep '.txt'`